# Total of array in batch

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get an average of an array in this code:

```
set /a arr[%b%]=%i%
```

where the %b% is set from 0 and b=b+1 and loops until it hits a number. The numbers in this array could vary.

Now I need to get an average of this arr[%b%] so I can display it at the end of the whole code.

Thank you

Comment: you need `(arr1+arr2+..arrn)/n` ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify this based on the size of the array:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set limit=10
set /a total=0
for /l %%a in (0, 1, %limit%) do set /a total+=!arr[%%a]!
set /a ave=%total%/%limit%

Echo Total:     %total%
Echo Average:   %ave%
```

And that should work for `arr[0]` to `arr[10]`.

Comment: but limit is not fixed...YOu'll need to count the elements

Comment: Thank you so much but at the end of the code, is says "missing operand". Everything else works though

Answer (score 0):

Monacraft answer is not bad ,but I prefer to calculate the array length.Here is a revised answer (plus added modulus)...

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::::::::just a test array::::::::::::
set /a arr[1]=1
set /a arr[2]=1
set /a arr[3]=1
set /a arr[4]=7
set /a arr[5]=2
set /a arr[6]=1
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


set /a total=0
for /f "delims=" %%# in ('set arr[^|find /c "="') do set "limit=%%#"
for /l %%a in (0, 1, %limit%) do set /a total+=!arr[%%a]!
set /a ave=total/limit
set /a mod=total%%limit

Echo Total:     %total%
Echo Average:   %ave%.%mod%
Echo Average(no mod):   %ave%
endlocal
```